# When will GWT 2.6 be Released?

Tags: gwt

Not to sound pushy, but does anyone know when GWT 2.6 is scheduled to be released.  The only thing I can find about it's release date is here:

http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2013/11/gwt-26-rc1-is-here.html

But it only mentions the RC release date.

Comment: I'd imagine only they would know. Why don't you try asking in the comments section on that page? It took about 4 months between the [2.5 RC announcement](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2012/06/gwt-2.html) and when [2.5 final was released](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2012/10/gwt-25-final-is-here.html).

Comment: It looks like a couple of people have asked there already, but haven't gotten a response.  I was just hoping that someone from the GWT dev team would be trolling StackOverflow :)

Comment: The gwt-contrib mailing list is an ideal place to ask these kinds of questions, since SO keeps its questions around for future askers, and after 2.6 ships, this will be a useless question. The short version is that GWT 2.6.0-rc4 went out a week and a half ago - try it out! if there are no bugs, we'll ship it as the final release!